# Sencha Touch - addAfter/insertAfter a component

Tags: javascript, extjs, sencha-touch-2

is it actually possible to addAfter or insertAfter for components?

The documentation goes on about .add() to throw something to the end of a container but I'm looping through field's in my form and displaying their errors after each one. So I need to add a new component after these.

It seems that it's only possible on the actual element of these components? something like:

```
errorElement = Ext.create('Ext.Container', {
    //stuff
});
errorElement.element.insertAfter(field.element);
```

This is fine, it looks fine but if I do the following, the component doesn't seem to exist where the Dom stuff is:

```
Ext.Viewport.getActiveItem().query('panel'); // []
Ext.ComponentQuery.query('panel'); // Ext.apply.create.Class
```

Please don't tell me that I'm the only person who is asking about this sort of thing, how is this not highlighted anywhere in the documentation?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [Container.insert()](http://docs.sencha.com/ext-js/4-0/#!/api/Ext.container.AbstractContainer-method-insert) method that `Inserts a Component into this Container at a specified index`.

However inserting an error Component (Component? not Element?) doesn't sound like a good idea. Default form fields already have an element for displaying errors inside them, and you can tweak its appearance through CSS.

Comment: Thanks. I can't see anything in the documentation about form fields being able to display errors inside them. I don't see anything within the DOM structure about error messages being displayed. How would this even work when the error handling is attached to the Model rather than the form? I'm currently running validate on my Model and putting a DataView of errors after the fields

Comment: what components do you use for your form items? can you provide a little code example?

Comment: See the definition of [Ext.form.MessageTargets](http://docs.sencha.com/ext-js/3-4/source/Field.html) and the public [markInvalid()](http://docs.sencha.com/ext-js/3-4/#!/api/Ext.form.Field-method-markInvalid) method of Ext.form.field